# Use QState.assignProperty with dynamic values at runtime

Tags: python, qt, properties, pyqt, qstatemachine

I have a question to using the `QStateMachine`-System of `PyQt5` properly.

Using

```
State.assignProperty(aLineEdit, "plainText", "Some text")
```

allows to set `"Some text"` to the `plainText`-property whenever `aState` is active.

**Question:** What if `"Some text"` is not constant or known before execution? My intention is to pass a function (not unlike connecting a `partial` or `lambda` expression to an event) instead of a value that would yield the appropriate value when the state is entered.

My only idea to emulate this behavior is to connect a function that sets the property to `aState.entered`. However I'm not happy with that solution because it mixes up the places where properties are set and a reason to use the `QStateMachine` is to avoid having to manually set states yourself.

Comment: Wouldn't a dynamic property undermine the logic of the state-machine? If a property can be either `A` or `B`, then that would seem to imply two different states.

Comment: @ekhumoro One could say that I now how the state of the property is defined (expressed for example by a method) when the respective machine state is active. Anyway, I just hope(d) that there is a way to use the state machine in a more flexible way.

Comment: The flexibility is provided by the `enter` and `exit` signals.

Answer (score 0):

Your only idea is correct, but you should factor it out into a helper method so that the function is invoked at the time the state is entered.